# Receive Bluetooth Events at application level Android

Tags: android, android-bluetooth

I'm developing an Android Application which is being controlled by another Android Application via Bluetooth.

The approach followed for this right now is, a handler is created in Main Activity, whose object is passed to a BG thread, and when there are Bluetooth actions received, the callbacks are triggered onto the Main Activity.

Now, this works fine only for Main Activity, because only this context is being passed to the thread.

I need this to be on Application level, i.e,

1. When application A sends BT message to app B, the message should be able to be processed on any Activity in app B (not some specific screen).

Please suggest how to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement this in a service, not in an activity. A service can run in the background, and does not need to be bound to a single activity.  Trying to implement this fuctionailty in an application on jet is not the right way to go.